# React Pass Image URL to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to render a different background image for a child component depending on the URL that is passed through props.

The background images are stored in the `public` folder under a file called `images`

```
public/images/bg_1.jpg
```

Current I have this:

> **Parent component**

```
import React from "react";
import Nav from "./Nav";
import SubNav from "./SubNav";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import PageHero from "./PageHero";
import backgroundImage from '../../public/images/bg_1.jpg';

const MainPage = () => (
  <div>
    <Nav />
    <SubNav company="Main Company" />
    <PageHero BackgroundURL={backgroundImage}/>
    <Footer />
  </div>
);

export default MainPage;
```

> **Child component (PageHero)**

```
import React from "react";

export class PageHero extends React.Component {
  render(props) {
    return (
      <div>
        <div
          class="page-hero uk-light"
          style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${props.BackgroundURL})` }}
        >
          <div class="uk-container uk-container-medium uk-text-center">
            <h1 class="uk-heading-primary page-hero__header uk-animation-fade">
              Page Heder
            </h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PageHero;
```

But I get this error when I try to link the src:

> ERROR in ./public/images/bg_1.jpg
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

is this possibly an issue with webpack or the way I'm referencing the image?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IMAGE: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45848055/image-you-may-need-an-appropriate-loader-to-handle-this-file-type)

Comment: Do you have something like {
    test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i, 
    loader: "file-loader?name=/public/icons/[name].[ext]"
} i your webpack.config.js

Comment: your webpack config needs to have the proper loader for image files to be handled.