# Image relative url not working in react js

Tags: reactjs

I have to display an image in my project so I gave a relative path in src properties but it is not working.

Anyone suggest me a solution.

Thanks

Comment: Please add some relevant code or info.  Its not possible to help with provided info

Answer (score 0):

You can import image as a component and directly use it:

```
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from "../../assets/logo.png";
```

And

```
<Logo className={classes.logo} />
```

Comment: When I am using the above code at it give me Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' error.

Comment: Are you using `create-react-app`? If not, please refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45848055/image-you-may-need-an-appropriate-loader-to-handle-this-file-type to use `file-loader` package to help you out.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the `import` instead of passing a path as a string.

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.png';

function Header() {
  return <img src={logo} alt="Logo" />;
}

export default Header;
```

For more information please visit [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files)

Comment: When I am using the above code at it give me Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' error.