# Reactjs don't render a local image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to load a image in my next.js project, however i'm using the native  from react.
The image is not loading in the page, so i'll be linkin my two js files (styles and the component) bellow.
I hope you can help me

```
import {Container, ProfileImage, Text} from './styles'

export default function Profile() {
    return (
        <Container>
            <ProfileImage 
                src="../../../public/images/profile.png"
            />
        </Container>
    )
}
```

```
import styled from 'styled-components'

export const Container = styled.div`
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    align-items:center;
    flex-direction:column;
`

export const ProfileImage = styled.img`
    border-radius:50%;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    border: 1px, black;
`
```

EDIT:
The full code is in:  https://github.com/FranciscoJLucca/franciscolucca.github.io

Comment: Does this answer your question? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999367/how-do-i-reference-a-local-image-in-react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999367/how-do-i-reference-a-local-image-in-react)

Comment: @rezso.dev  not actually, when I try anyone of the ways in this answer I get a error, like: 
`./public/images/profile.png 1:0 Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders (Source code omitted for this binary file)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who tried to help, but I found out what was going on.
By default, Next.js only loads images that are inside the `/public` folder and in order for it to recognize other paths, a library had to be added, [next-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-images), I also had to create a configuration file for next.js, the `next.config.js` which follows below.

```
const withImages = require ('next-images')
module.exports = withImages ({
    esModule: true,
})
```

I get this information in [next.js image optimization](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend importing the image as a component then calling it in your function. I had a similar issue in the past and that solved my problem!
Example:

```
import {yourImage} from "../yourfolder/Image.png"
export default function Profile() {
return (
 <img src={yourImage}></img>
  )
```

Comment: That's odd. Have you made sure your path is correct? I do know this is a common mistake that can occur sometimes. I'll also take a look at you repo! :)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** I took a look at the repo, two things you have to fix:

1. Fix typo: `styled.image` -> `styled.img`
2. Use absolute path excluding public directory: `src='/images/Profile.png'`

**Old answer:** You might need to configure a loader for webpack. I suggest url-loader, there is a handy guide in the accepted answer here: [IMAGE: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45848055/image-you-may-need-an-appropriate-loader-to-handle-this-file-type)

Comment: Unfortunately it dosent work , I really dont know what is happening, it is blowing my mind hahaha

Comment: Have you tried a minimal example with another image?

Comment: Yes, I tried with some google images and diferentes extensions and wont work

Comment: OK, I see you have edited your question and added a repo link. Let me take a look at it. We are gonna solve this :)

Answer (score 0):

The `src` should be like this.

```
                src="/images/profile.png"
```

Just don't use exact path ../../public.
It won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Please Import your image like this.

```
import {youjsrImage} from "/sourceDirectory";
```

then use the code in render function like :

```js
<img src={yourImage}></img>
```