# Nextjs: Why are images from the public folder not loading?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, shopify, shopify-app

From the `public` folder in the root of my project there is an image: `download.png`. In my js file, I call it like so: `<img src={"/download.png"} />`. However, the image doesn't load as illustrated [here](https://paste.pics/9cd3be2b8d4133ba251a85c97f50a250)

In devTools, the correct element is displayed: `<img src="/download.png">`

When I try and directly import the png file: `import download from "../public/download.png"`, I get the following error:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
┃ You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders 
are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

I also started a new Nextjs project with the exact same implementation described above and the `download.png` image loaded from the `public` folder.

Another thing I tried was to use the nextjs `<Image/>` component. However, that did not load an image either (result was blank).

I'm using a custom server that was scaffolded with [Shopify's library](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-demo-app-node-react/blob/master/server.js)

How do get get images to load into my project from the `public` folder?

Comment: Can you try solution mentioned here ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45848055/image-you-may-need-an-appropriate-loader-to-handle-this-file-type

Comment: I'll test it out, thanks!

Comment: Please add the code you have in your custom server file.

Answer (score -1):

try using Image tag

```
   import Image from 'next/image';
```

Comment: This is not working.