# Img wont show Reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, image

New react developer, i'm using webpack and trying to load image, but it wont show it and it is not giving me any error, any idea ?

webpack:

```js
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?[a-z0-9=.]+)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000',
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx', '.tsx', '.ts'],
  },
};
```

```js
import Immage from '../../icons/MicrosoftTeamsImage.png';


          <img src={require('../../icons/MicrosoftTeamsImage.png')} alt="icon" />


also tried like this:

<img src={Immage} alt="some example image" alt="icon" />
```

it shows like this:

[image]

those i installed like this: yarn add --save file-loader url-loader

edit:  I checked network tab and status is 200, but it shows Request URL: http://..../[object%20Module] i tried to fix it like this <img src={require('../../icons/MicrosoftTeamsImage.png').default} alt="icon" /> and now it says : Request URL: http://..../29691089ca26d06beb2854d687a560cf.png but still image wont show

Comment: any help is appreciated !

Comment: What does dev tools say? 404? Is it trying to load from the right URL?

Comment: (on a different note, no currently supported browsers need fonts in formats that aren't woff2 or woff, definitely worth removing eot, ttf. Those are _not_ meant to be used online anymore. One's a dead format, the other is superfluous because every browser that supports ttf also supports the far smaller woff/woff2 formats)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans there is nothing in console, no errors...

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans i did according to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46640129/17292277

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans should there also be         loader: "file-loader",
 ?

Comment: @walee the ONLY way that console wouldn't be showing some error (like 404 or other http error while loading an image) is that this image simply looks like this

Comment: @FlashThunder no when i open it in visual studio it is big image

Comment: If the image doesn't load, the console tab will show errors, and the network tab will show requests with a status that isn't 200. Make sure both console and network tabs are not set to any particular filter, so they show _all_ errors. Also, do an "inspect element" on  your image, and copy its outerhtml, then put that in your post so that people can see what real DOM your react code turns into.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans i checked network tab and status is 200, but it shows Request URL: http://..../[object%20Module]  i tried to fix it like this   <img
            src={require('../../icons/MicrosoftTeamsImage.png').default}
            alt="icon"
          />      and now it says : Request URL: http://..../29691089ca26d06beb2854d687a560cf.png  but still image wont show

Comment: Don't tell me in a comment, tell everyone by working those missing details [into your post](/help/how-to-ask). People asking for details are not asking for themselves, they're trying to get you to improve your question so that _everyone_ can help answer it =)

Answer (score 0):

Take the directory **icons** that contains the image and put it inside the **src** directory.

Then adjust the path of the image to be as:

```
import Immage from '../icons/MicrosoftTeamsImage.png';
```

And then use this syntax:

```
<img src={Immage} alt="some example image" alt="icon" />
```

Comment: i did it like that but getting nothing and no errors

Comment: my question already does this and here you have two 'alt'